# Add custom button on Mapbox's navigation view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, mapbox, nslayoutconstraint

I am using Mapbox to allow users to navigate between locations. I am using basic navigation feature as stated in the documentation (https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/navigation/examples/basic/). This gives me the navigation view as below.
[image]

I would like to add a custom button at the bottom of the view. For this, I tried the following code.

```
Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in

    guard let route = routes?.first else {
        self.showAlertMessage("No possible routes detected")
        return
    }

    self.mapNavigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: route)

    self.mapNavigationViewController.delegate = self

    self.present(self.mapNavigationViewController, animated: true, completion: {

        let customButton = UIButton()
        customButton.setTitle("Press", for: .normal)
        customButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        customButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)

        self.mapNavigationViewController.view.addSubview(customButton)

        customButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapNavigationViewController.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapNavigationViewController.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapNavigationViewController.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        self.mapNavigationViewController.view.setNeedsLayout()

    })
}
```

With this, I got the button as below.

[image]

Now, the next thing to be done is to shift the mapbox's view so that its bottom aligns with the custom button's top. How can I achieve this?

Comment: autolayout constraints

Comment: I am facing difficulty in using auto layout constraints programmatically @DaniSpringer

Comment: Instead of `customButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapNavigationViewController.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true`. Why not `customButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapNavigationViewController.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true`

Comment: The button does not display with the above substitution.

Comment: Are you able to write code to affect the constraints of the map? Or is that out of your control? If yes: set map top to safe are top, map bottom to button top, and button bottom to safe area bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to accomplish the task following this Mapbox [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/navigation/examples/embedded-navigation/).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your objective, you will have to change the bottom constraint of the map view implemented in the library. So that you can set its bottom constraint equal to the top constraint of your `customButton`

See if you have access to the library's map view or its bottom constraint.